# Circumcircle of triangle $ABC$

Tags: vectors

> In an equilateral triangle $ABC$  if $P$ be any point of the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ and $R$ represent radius of that circle.
>
> Then find $\displaystyle \frac{|\vec{PA}|^2+
> |\vec{PB}|^2+|\vec{PC}|^2}{R^2}$

Try: assuming position vector of $C$ is $\vec{0}$ and $A,B,P$ respectively $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{p}$.

So $$|\vec{PA}|^2+
|\vec{PB}|^2+|\vec{PC}|^2=|\vec{p}-\vec{a}|^2+|\vec{p}-\vec{b}|^2+|\vec{p}-\vec{0}|^2=3|\vec{p}|^2+|\vec{a}|^2+|\vec{b}|^2-2\bigg(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{a}+\vec{p}\cdot\vec{b}\bigg)$$

Could some help me to solve it, thanks

Comment: Better to choose your origin at the centre of the circle to exploit symmetry, Then the sum of the position vectors of the vertices is equal to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the centre of the triangle as the origin $O$.

\begin{align*}
&\;\frac{|\vec{PA}|^2+|\vec{PB}|^2+|\vec{PC}|^2}{R^2}\\
=&\;\frac{|\vec{OA}|^2+|\vec{OB}|^2+|\vec{OC}|^2+3|\vec{OP}|^2-2\vec{OP}\cdot(\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC})}{R^2}\\
=&\;\frac{3R^2+3R^2-2\vec{OP}\cdot(\vec{0})}{R^2}\\
=&\;6
\end{align*}

Comment: I did not understand why $\vec{OP}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{OA},\vec{OB},\vec{OC}.$ please explain.

Comment: It is not. But we have $\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}=\vec{0}$.

Answer (score 2):

$PA^2+PB^2+PC^2$ is the moment of inertia of $\{A,B,C\}$ with respect to $P$. In an equilateral triangle the centroid $G$ and the circumcenter $O$ are the same point, hence by [the parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem), for any point $P$ on the circumcircle of an equilateral triangle $ABC$ we have

$$ PA^2+PB^2+PC^2 = 3 OP^2 + OA^2+OB^2+OC^2 = 6R^2.$$